# Digispark don't work when I power it by 5v and GND inputs and chip starts heating

Tags: digispark

I'm beginner so probably I did something stupid, but now my digispark don't work when I power it by 5v and GND inputs but chip starts heating immediately. When I power it by USB everything works well. Did i broke it? And how can I check it?

Comment: Did you connect it backwards?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I connect backwards my power supply to dashboard. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connected the power backwards - so all the current is being shunted straight through the ESD protection diodes (and likely other routes too) generating lots of heat and risking permanent damage to the MCU.

Take better care next time...